# Converting from decimal to IEEE floating point when the exponent is negative

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

So I'm converting floating to decimal and decimal to float but with different number of exp and frac bits.
When converting from decimal, I need to make sure it has 1 signed bit, 4 exponent bits and 4 frac bits.

Converting this value is troubling me:

`-1^1*1+1/4*2^(-9)`

because the exponent would be -9 + 7 (e + bias), which is -2. How would I represent -2 in 4 bits? Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: `-1*1+1/4*2^(-9)` does not look like a number that would be used in this kind of problem. Is the original −1 to the power of one, then multiplied by 1/4 and by 2 to the power of −9? If so, an exponent of −9 is below the lower bound of what you can represent in a four-bit exponent field with the usual encoding (7 bias), in which case the correct answer may be that the number rounds to 0.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, you're right. How would I round it to 0?

Comment: 1110?..........

Comment: @Uberi_Puip: I do not understand your question “How would I round it to 0?” If you are doing this manually, with pencil and paper, then, when you determine the answer should be zero, you write all zeros for the bits. If you are doing this with a C program, then, when you determine the answer should be zero, likely with an `if` statement at the right place, you return 0 (which has zeros for all its bits).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, so do I just make the exponent bits 0000?

Comment: @S.S.Anne I'm not sure what that means. 1110 is 14 in binary (unsigned), what is its significance here?

Comment: Does your format have subnormal numbers? If not, round to zero should result in all zeros, except for the sign bit if the number being rounded was negative and your format has signed zero.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Ah okay. I recently came across round to even and am confused if I should be doing that. Thank you

Comment: "How would I represent -2 in 4 bits?" 1110. But biased -2 would be 0101, because 7-2 is 5.

Comment: please correct the expression as Eric comment above